# Internet Explorer 11 and <iframe> document mode inheritance

Tags: internet-explorer, inheritance, iframe

**Situation:**

I have a site that is being loaded on another system inside an `<frame>` that is out my control. Inside my page I have set IE to target the latest version: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`. When opened by itself the site looks great and the web inspector tells me that it is in Edge mode.

When I open the site inside of the other system, the web inspector is telling me the default mode is **7** and it is being set because **Via X-UA-compatible HTTP header:** This is also because the server is sending down a HTTP response header of `X-UA-Compatible, IE=EmulateIE7`.

The page *frames.aspx* -- that contains the `<frameset>` & `<frame>` already has a HTML5 DOCTYPE declared but no X-UA `<meta>` tag.

**Question:**

I thought that the X-UA `<meta>` tag inside my site would overwrite the server's response header....Or is it that because the *frames.aspx* page does not contain a X-UA `<meta>` tag so then IE7 mode is being set on that parent page (via HTTP response header) then it is being inherited down to my site?

Would love to hear any thoughts on this situation.